# Set Value of HiddenField in GridView to new GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, guid

I have a GridView control with an ItemTemplate that has a HiddenField.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...>
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value='<% Response.Write(Guid.NewGuid()) %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The problem is that it actually renders exactly `<% Response.Write(Guid.NewGuid()) %>` instead of a Guid. How do I set the value to render as a Guid and execute the code rather than interpret it as a literal. I've tried using both single quotes ' and double quotes ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%# Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You have to add `#` In inline coding . Ex : `'<%#  //code here %>'` and
you are setting `HiddenField1` `value` ,so you dont need to use `Response.Write` . The `value` should be  `Value='<%# Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>'` . Hope this will do

Answer (score 2):

You can **get** the GUID in code behind as follows.

```
HiddenField HiddenField1 = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("HiddenField1");
Guid guid1;
Guid1.TryParse(HiddenField1.Value, out guid1);
```

To **set** the value, you can use

```
HiddenField1.Value = guid1.ToString();
```

Comment: So it can't be done inline? Also, I forgot to mention it is an .ascx user control.

Comment: I haven't tried using incline coding, sorry about that!

Comment: Would I use the OnRowCreated event to set the HiddenField for each row in the code behind?

Comment: Best way would be is through `RowDataBound`